# Wrong Camera Orientation with Android & Vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia, android-hardware

We are developing our own Android-based hardware and we wish to use Vuforia (developed via Unity3D) for certain applications. However, we are having problems making Vuforia work well with our current camera orientation settings.

On our hardware, when the camera is placed horizontally - everything works fine. That is, when the camera is parallel to the placement of the display. However, we need to place the camera vertically, or in other words, with a 90 degree difference to the placement of the display. These are all hardware settings. Our kernel is programmed according to such settings and every other program that utilises the camera works compatibly with everything, including our IMU sensors. However, apps developed with Vuforia behave completely odd when the camera is placed vertically.

We assume the problem to be related to Vuforia's algorithms of processing raw camera data however we are not sure. Moreover, we do not know how to fix the situation. For further details, I can list:

-When "Enable Video Background" is on, the projected image is distorted and no video feed is available. The AR projection appears on a black background with distorted dimensions.

-When "Enable Video Background" is on and the device is rotated, the black background is replaced by flickering solid colors.

-When "Enable Video Background" is off, the AR projection has normal dimensions (no distortion) however it is tracked with wrong axis settings. For example, when the target moves left in real world, the projection moves up.

-When "Enable Video Background" is off and the device is rotated, the AR projection is larger compared to its appearance when the device is in it's default state.

I will be glad to provide any more information you need.

Thank you very much, have a nice day.

PS: We have found out that applications that use the camera as a main purpose (Camera apps, Barcode Scanners, etc) work fine while apps for which camera usage is an extra quality (such as some games) have the same problem as Vuforia.  This make me think that apps who access the camera directly work fine whereas those who use Android API and classes fail for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

First understand that every platform deals with cameras differently and that beyond this different android phone manufacturers deal with these differently as well. In my testing WITHOUT vuforia I had to transform the plane I cast the video feed onto 0,-90,90 for android/iphone and -270,-90,90 for the windows surface tablet. Past this the iPhone rear camera was mirrored, the android front camera was mirrored as well as the surface front camera. That is easy to account for, but an annoying issue is that the Google Pixel and Samsung front cameras were mirrored across the y (as were ALL iOS on the back camera), but the Nexus 6p was mirrored across the x. What I am getting at here is that there are a LOT of devices to account for with android so try more than just that one device. Vuforia so far has dealt with my pixel and 4 of my iOS devices just fine.

As for how to fix your problem:

Go into your player settings for unity and look at the orientation. There are a few options here and my application only uses portrait so I force portrait and it seems to work fine (none of the problems I had to account for with the above mentioned scenario). Vuforia previously did NOT support auto rotation so you need to make sure you have the latest version since it sounds like that is what you need. If the auto rotate is set and it is not working right you may have to account for that specific device (don't do this for all devices until after you test those devices). To account for that device use an if (or construct a case statement if you have multiple instances of this problem with different devices) and then reflect or translate as needed. Cross platform development systems (like unity) doesn't always get everything perfect since there is basically no standard. In these cases you have to directly account for them by creating a method and a case statement within that so you can cleanly and modularly manipulate all necessary devices. It is a pain, but it beats developing for all devices separately.

One more thing is make sure you check out the vuforia configuration file as it has some settings such as camera mirror and direction settings on there. These seem to be public settings so you should also be able to script to these in your case statement in the event you need to use "Flip Horizontally" for one phone, but not another.